# Send data to REST API after getting auth token

Tags: asp.net, rest

I am using ASP.NET2.0

I am trying to code a web page that can send job data to a job board (in this case Gumtree).

I have to obtain an auth token first via a url and then send the data back again containing the auth token, but I do not know the best way to go about this using asp.net2.0. I am using VB but can convert from c#

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I have not tried anything yet as I don't really know where to start.  I have been told what I need to do, just not how to achieve it using ASP.NET(VB).

Comment: A [rest api tutorial](http://www.restapitutorial.com/) would be a good place to start.